# Why $\vec{\mathfrak{m}}$ and $\vec{J}$ are collinear when considering precession in magnetic field?

Tags: magnetic-fields, angular-momentum, magnetic-moment, precession

Recently I have read about magentization of paramagnetic materials and precession of atoms in magnetic field. So, I found the following formula: $\vec{\mathfrak{m}} = \Gamma \vec{J}$, where $\vec{\mathfrak{m}}$ is magnetic moment, $\vec{J}$ is angular momentum and $\Gamma$ is gyromagnetic ratio. My question is: why $\vec{\mathfrak{m}}$ and $\vec{J}$ are collinear?